# jquery toggle a form action and submit button text

Tags: jquery, forms, toggle

I have a list of organizations and buttons (mini-forms) next to each organization allowing the user to join/leave the organization.

Each button either says "join" (with action /org/ID/join) or "leave" (with action /org/ID/leave). None of these forms have a unique ID attribute and I am constrained in a way where I cannot add this ID attribute for each form. But all the actions are unique.

I want to ajaxify the join/leave process, toggling the button text and action appropriately as a user joins/leaves the organization.

What is the most efficient/cleanest way of achieving this using jquery?

Comment: Just to be sure, you cannot add the organisation ID to the form?

Comment: Basically, you cannot add an ID attribute to the form tag or any of its input tags. The only presence of the organization ID is in the action.

Answer (score 0):

If I get you correct, you can add a class attribute on each join/leave process and on document.ready, you can iterate through the class to do the process.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a button with a PUT request, that PUT's to the url /org/ID/join and /org/ID/leave. You can do this a few ways, but using jquery's ajax call allows you to **both** sent the PUT request, and define the callback function.

The callback function is where you will change the button's text from join to leave, and leave to join, as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate through each form (in my example I assume they all have the same class). By default the button value is set to "Join" and if something is checked i.e. they are a member already (something == true) it would change the value to "Leave".

This is a really basic example but may give you some direction.

```
$('.organization').each(function() {
    if (something == true) {
       $(this).find('input[type="submit"]').attr('value', 'Leave');
    }
});
```